# Is it possible to sort each group in groupBy in a simple way?

Tags: sorting, kotlin, grouping

I have a function which groups my highscore list into groups for each category, but when I get the groups, they are not in order anymore and the person with the highest score, is placed some random place in the list.

I was wondering if there is a simple way I can just sort each group.

My grouping function looks like this:

```kotlin
private fun getCategories(scores: List<HighScore>): List<Pair<String, List<HighScore>>> {
    return scores.groupBy {
        it.word.category
    }.toList()
}
```

My model looks like this

```kotlin
data class HighScore(
    val ID: String?,
    val player: String,
    val time: Int,
    val hints: Int,
    val wrongs: Int,
    val word: Word
) {
    fun getScore():Int {
        return time*word.difficulty/hints/(wrongs+1)
    }
}
```

and my old sorting function looks like this (but i guess I could just use `sortedByDescending()`

```kotlin
private fun order(scores: ArrayList<HighScore>): List<HighScore> {
    scores
        .sortWith(kotlin.Comparator { lhs, rhs ->
            when {
                lhs.getScore() > rhs.getScore() -> -1
                lhs.getScore() < rhs.getScore() -> 1
                else -> 0
            }
        })

    return if (scores.size > 10) {
        scores.slice(0 until 10)
    } else {
        scores
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve your function to something like this:

```
    private fun getCategories(scores: List<HighScore>): List<Pair<String, List<HighScore>>> {
        return scores
            .sortedByDescending { it.getScore() }
            .groupBy { it.word.category }
            .mapValues { it.value.take(10) }
            .map { Pair(it.key, it.value) }
    }
```

It may be even simpler if you use just `Map<String, List<HighScore>>` instead of `List<Pair<String, List<HighScore>>>` as your return type:

```
    private fun getCategories(scores: List<HighScore>): Map<String, List<HighScore>> {
        return scores
            .sortedByDescending { it.getScore() }
            .groupBy { it.word.category }
            .mapValues { it.value.take(10) }
    }
```

You can now pass your `List<HighScore>` in any order in the function and it will always return high scores grouped by category, sorted from the highest and each group will have at most 10 elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't understand how the sorting function can work on the list after it is grouped when it is called before.